# Setting Focus on iframe on a long page when scrolled

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Trying to set focus on an iframe on a web page, only when it's visible on the web page!
Considering the situation that we have a long scrollable page and the iframe is placed at the end of the page.

Expectation - As I will scroll the page and set focus on the iframe so as to autoplay the video in that iframe.

If someone can help with this event handling in javascript?

Comment: Where is the code that is not working for you? :)

Comment: Don’t focus primarily on the iframe - how to do something when an element is scrolled into view, is something you should be able to research, because that is anything but a new question.

Comment: @CBroe exactly my point, I am trying to figure out to make changes when the particular element is visible on the screen!

Comment: And what did you do so far to “figure this out”? What have you _researched_, what results did you come up with through that, and what have you tried?

Comment: http://patik.com/code/within-viewport/